# Permission denied on files downloaded by Transmission

Tags: permissions, mdadm, bittorrent, transmission

On a fresh installation of Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 I installed Transmission using this procedure:

```
sudo apt-get install transmission-cli transmission-common transmission-daemon
sudo service transmission-daemon stop
sudo nano /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info/settings.json
```

In the settings I changed download and incomplete folder destinations and `umask` set to "2", and add my username to `debian-transmission` group

```
sudo usermod -a -G debian-transmission username
sudo service transmission-daemon start
```

First download give me `permission denied` after few seconds.

So I tried to change the ownership and permissions on folders:

```
sudo chown username:debian-transmission /media/public/downloads
sudo chmod 770 /media/public/downloads
```

(The same have been done for for incompelete folder) but the problem is the same.

I attach output of `ps -ef | grep transmission`.

```
debian-+ 984 1 0 08:02 ? 00:01:30 /usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error
username 4365 4350 0 17:20 pts/17 00:00:00 grep --color=auto transmission
```

and `ps aux | grep transmission`.

```
debian-+ 984 0.2 0.2 345376 17516 ? Ssl 08:02 1:30 /usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error
username 4369 0.0 0.0 21312 976 pts/17 S+ 17:21 0:00 grep --color=auto transmission
```

Output of `ls -l /media/public/downloads` is:

```
drwxrwx---+ 2 username debian-transmission
```

The last information that could be useful to understand my situation is the incomplete and download folders are on *mdadm* device but I don't know how give you more details about it

Comment: Transmission is already installed and doesn't require any additional groups?? And permissions have to do with the partition/folder you're downloading to and not how or with what they were downloaded? I really don't understand why you're doing all that.

Comment: Hi @CelticWarrion, I started all this assuming that transmission was not present in default Ubuntu installation. So probably I did it for nothing :( . I'll let you know. Thanks for this info

Comment: It is but even if not installed by default the first option should always be checking the official repositories where you would find it. It doesn't require special settings but if you change the default folders make sure you have rw permissions for the user running Transmission. Also applicable to any other then the default download location you may decide to download to eventually.

Comment: It's installed only client version, I spoke about server version. The permission on download folder are in the last lines of my main post

Answer (score 0):

the only work around that I found to solve this problem is to edit /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon and set the "USER" variable to "root"

I know it's not the right way but is the only one that allow transmission daemon to write files in destination folders